# Json array + object mapper

Tags: java, android, json

Имеем `json`

```
{
  "cities": [
    {
      "name": "Pyongyang",
      "id": "1871859",
      "country": "North Korea",
      "countryId": "1873107"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pune",
      "id": "1259229",
      "country": "India",
      "countryId": "1269750"
    },
    {
      "name": "Paris",
      "id": "2988507",
      "country": "France",
      "countryId": "3017382"
    }
  ]
}
```

С помощью `retrofit`

```
private RetrofitClient() {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Configuration.SERVER_API_URL)
            .client(getOkHttpClient())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(getObjectMapper()))
            .build();
}


private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        objectMapper.setVisibilityChecker(objectMapper
                .getSerializationConfig()
                .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)    
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.DEFAULT)  
                .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)   
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)); 
        return objectMapper;
}
```

Сам класс City

```
    @JsonRootName(value = "cities")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonPropertyOrder({
            "name",
            "id",
            "country",
            "countryId"
    })
    public class City implements Parcelable{

        @JsonProperty("name")
        private String name;
        @JsonProperty("id")
        private String id;
        @JsonProperty("country")
        private String country;
        @JsonProperty("countryId")
        private String countryId;
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        public City() {
        }

        @JsonProperty("name")
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @JsonProperty("name")
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @JsonProperty("id")
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @JsonProperty("id")
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @JsonProperty("country")
        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        @JsonProperty("country")
        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        @JsonProperty("countryId")
        public String getCountryId() {
            return countryId;
        }

        @JsonProperty("countryId")
        public void setCountryId(String countryId) {
            this.countryId = countryId;
        }

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
            return this.additionalProperties;
        }

        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
            this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
        }
```

Как мне с помощью object mapper правильно парсить json, так как он выводит все значения в "не понимаемые"?
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Скажите, а с таким json можете подсказать, почему не работает?

{"path":"http://*.com/uploads/world/europe/france/cities/paris/inst/","logo":"logo_sm.png","list":[{"id":"757","name":"AAA","slug":"apprendre-approfondir-accomplir"},{"id":"1474","name":"ACCORD","slug":"accord-french-language-school"},{"id":"749","name":"Alliance Fran\u00e7aise","slug":"alliance-francaise"},{"id":"1672","name":"CCFS","slug":"ccfs-cours-de-civilisation-francaise-de-la-sorbonne-fle-"},{"id":"1472","name":"Ecole Suisse Internationale","slug":"ecole-suisse-internationale"},{"id":"1538","name":"EF","slug":"ef-international-language-school"},{"id":"1674","name":"EFI","slug":"ecole-privee-de-francais-pour-linternational"},{"id":"1546","name":"ELFE","slug":"elfe-ecole-de-langue-francaise-pour-etrangers-"},{"id":"1566","name":"Eurocentres language school","slug":"eurocentres-language-school"},{"id":"1653","name":"France Langue Paris Notre-Dame","slug":"france-langue-paris-notre-dame"},{"id":"981","name":"France Langue Paris Op\u00e9ra","slug":"france-langue-paris-opera"},{"id":"1654","name":"France Langue Paris Victor Hugo","slug":"france-langue-paris-victor-hugo"},{"id":"1537","name":"L'Etoile","slug":"letoile"},{"id":"1514","name":"LSI","slug":"lsi-6"},{"id":"752","name":"Lutece Langue","slug":"lutece-langue"},{"id":"1466","name":"L\u2019Atelier 9","slug":"latelier-9"},{"id":"1561","name":"OISE","slug":"oise"},{"id":"1671","name":"Paris Langues (Member CEI)","slug":"paris-langues-member-cei-"},{"id":"121","name":"Sprachcaffe Paris","slug":"sprachcaffe-languages-plus-paris"},{"id":"755","name":"Verlaine Langue","slug":"verlaine-langue"},{"id":"756","name":"Vis-\u0430-Vis","slug":"vis_a_vis"}],"empty":"I'm just a tourist"}

retrofit для всех одинаковый

Вот 2 класса (по Вашей подсказке, сделал аналогично и тут)

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "path",
        "logo",
        "list",
        "empty"
})
public class School {

    @JsonProperty("path")
    private String path;
    @JsonProperty("logo")
    private String logo;
    @JsonProperty("list")
    private List<Schools> list = new ArrayList<>();
    @JsonProperty("empty")
    private String empty;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public School() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param logo
     * @param empty
     * @param path
     * @param list
     */
    public School(String path, String logo, List<Schools> list, String empty) {
        this.path = path;
        this.logo = logo;
        this.list = list;
        this.empty = empty;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The path
     */
    @JsonProperty("path")
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param path
     * The path
     */
    @JsonProperty("path")
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The logo
     */
    @JsonProperty("logo")
    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param logo
     * The logo
     */
    @JsonProperty("logo")
    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The list
     */
    @JsonProperty("list")
    public List<Schools> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param list
     * The list
     */
    @JsonProperty("list")
    public void setList(List<Schools> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The empty
     */
    @JsonProperty("empty")
    public String getEmpty() {
        return empty;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param empty
     * The empty
     */
    @JsonProperty("empty")
    public void setEmpty(String empty) {
        this.empty = empty;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}






@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "id",
        "name",
        "slug"
})
public class Schools {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("slug")
    private String slug;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public Schools() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * @param name
     * @param slug
     */
    public Schools(String id, String name, String slug) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The slug
     */
    @JsonProperty("slug")
    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param slug
     * The slug
     */
    @JsonProperty("slug")
    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

    //region ==================== toString() ====================

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    //endregion

}
```

Запрос выглядит так

```
@GET("/schools/city/{id}")
        Observable<School> getSchoolList(@Path("id") String id);
```

Comment: А какой тип вы скармливаете ретрофиту? City?

Comment: List<City> могу еще кода выложить, для полноты картины

Comment: public interface CityService {
  @GET("geo/cities/search/{searchQuery}")
  Observable<List<City>> getCities(@Path("searchQuery") String searchQuery);
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ретрофиту отдать этот класс будет парсить.

```
   public class Cities {

        @JsonProperty("cities")
        private ArrayList<City> cities;

        public ArrayList<City> getCities() {
            return cities;
        }

        public void setCities(ArrayList<City> cities) {
            this.cities = cities;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример, как бы Вы это скормили retrofit'у?

Comment: `Observable<Cities> getCities(@Path("searchQuery") String searchQuery);` как то так

Comment: Благодарю, вынес в отдельный класс и пришло всё в красивом виде, спасибо большое!

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, как быть с более сложным json? Если будет возможность, посмотрите.